# Generate labels for each line in plot generated by DataFrameGroupBy objects

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

So far, with the help of you all from SO, I have managed to create a DataFrame from a CSV file, grouped it from column A-Q (they are distinctive only together), and managed to get a graph with each group comprising one line on the graph with following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 12))
for element, group in groups:
    group.plot(x='R', y='Standardized Value', ax=ax,
               marker='o')
plt.ylim(1, 1.2)
plt.show()
```

So far, the graph looks almost like what I wanted: each point has a marker, and each group makes up one line on the graph. However, the legend that is automatically created by the graph says *Standardized Value* for each line colour. I want the columns to be made up of the content of column C, M, P, and Q for each group (any one of the rows in a group works, I don't much care). I thought I could do this by changing my code like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 12))
for element, group in groups:
    group.plot(x='R', y='Standardized Value', ax=ax,
               marker='o', label=group[['C', 'M',
                                        'P', 'Q']])
plt.ylim(1, 1.2)
plt.show()
```

But I get a ValueError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-142-df5e3ddd91ea>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/LL/.spyder-py3/unbenannt0.py', wdir='C:/Users/LL/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/LL/.spyder-py3/unbenannt0.py", line 70, in <module>
    'P', 'Q']])

  File "C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 783, in __call__
    label_name = label_kw or y

  File "C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1555, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any idea why this is happening? And how I can resolve it?

P.S.: I feel bad always just asking for help, and never being able to give it. But I promise I am looking through new questions. However, there wasn't anything to which I knew the answer until now.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the group is in `element` and it'll be given as a tuple. This tuple contains the multi-level grouping you made of columns A-Q. Assuming Column C is the third column, you should be able to access the value in Column C using `label=element[2]`.

Or, more generally, you can do:

```py
groupby_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', ... 'Q']
for element, group in groups:
  label_cols = ['C', 'M', 'P', 'Q']

  ### groupby_cols.index('C') identifies the position of `C` in your groupby list.
  ### element[groupby_cols.index('C')] takes the item in that same position from the element tuple, so that's less susceptible to human error.
  label_names = [element[groupby_cols.index(i)] for i in label_cols]

  ### Join the values of the 4 columns
  full_label_name = ', '.join(label_names)
  group.plot(..., label=full_label_name)
```

Alternatively, if you want to do more than joining the values in the columns with a comma, you can use f-strings:

```py
full_label_name = f"ColumnC is {label_names[0]}, Other columns are {label_names[3]}, {label_names[2]}, {label_names[1]}"
```

in which the things within the curly braces would be evaluated and placed at that position in the f-string

Comment: This DOES work for a single column's value, but not if I want to use multiple columns. When I do `label=(element[2], element[4])`, I have parentheses around the labels in my legend, and there is a random _None, None_ on top that looks like a title for the legend.

I have worked around it with the `%`-format like so: `label='%s, %s, %s, %s' % (group.iloc[0]['C'], group.iloc[0]['M'], group.iloc[0]['P'], group.iloc[0]['Q'])`, but I do not quite understand what I am doing there with the `[0]`, and I believe that `%` is deprecated (or disfavoured?) with most Pythonists?

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood your question. I'll edit my answer accordingly. 
group is a dataframe, so when you do group.iloc[0]['C'], you are selecting the value in the first row, column C of that dataframe. If you didn't do [0], your selection would be the entire column C, i.e. a Series. 
I think % is deprecated and replaced with f strings (See my answer)